# how to set longest li element's width as width of all li elements that belong to single parent ul

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I have an unordered list like this

```
<ul class="dropdown">Home
    <li>Kithchen</li>
    <li>Meeting room</li>
    <li>Garden</li>
</ul>
```

When I `mouseover` on home, the width of all `<li>` elements coming under home should be the width of longest element. For example here 'Meeting room' is longest.

I need to do this using 'jQuery'

Thanks in advance

The `CSS` file I have written for the menu is like this

```
ul                          { list-style: none;}

/* 
    LEVEL ONE
*/
ul.dropdown                 {text-align:left; position:relative;z-index:1; width:1000px;}
ul.dropdown li              { font-weight: bold;border:1px solid green; float:left;color:white;background: black;width:100% }
ul.dropdown a:hover         { color: white; }
ul.dropdown a:active        { color: white; }
ul.dropdown li a            { text-align:left; display:inline; padding:4px; color:white;}
ul.dropdown li:last-child a { border-right: none; } /* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li:hover        { background: orange; color: white; position:relative; }
*                           { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

/* 
    LEVEL TWO
*/
.dropdown ul                { width: 220px; visibility:hidden; position:absolute;  left: 0; }
ul.dropdown ul li           { font-weight: normal; background:black; color: white; float:left; }

                            /* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
ul.dropdown ul li a         {color:White; border-right: none; width:180px; display: inline-block; } 

/* 
    LEVEL THREE
*/
ul.dropdown ul ul           { left: 100px; top: 0; }
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul   { visibility: visible;}
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery to do this. Basic CS can do this, but we will need a bit more first. `<li>` and `<ul>` elements are essentially block-level, so without more context, we are not going to be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is there a reason why you don't want to use

```
ul.dropdown li { display: block; width: 100%; }
```

??

**edit:**

thanks for the jsfiddle link, but the demo you've set up doesn't work at the present time.

I suggest you use one of the many free css dropdown menu generators, at least as a base, to see how they work.  One I've used before and can recommend is http://purecssmenu.com/ .  That should get you going properly.

Comment: @bhargav -- now that you've added some code, I can see that your Level 1 `ul.dropdown li` has `float:left`, which will cause it to shrink.  Why don't you create mock-up on http://jsfiddle.net/ and then we can fix it for you?

Comment: @simon ok...i m trying to put my mock in the link

Comment: @simon i have edited and checked in jsfiddle but how do you get that link...i gues this is the link http://jsfiddle.net/hJPmT/9/

Comment: @bhargav -- when you've got it set up in jsfiddle, click "save" and post the url (in your question).  Then we can fork your fiddle, and return you a link to a solution :)

Comment: @simonn i hope i can be more clear if i can chat wid u directly..the thing is the kitchen and etc chldren also gets the black backgrond around them..but i donno y it isnt been shown over there...

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using Javascript for display where possible. I think you can solve this using strickly CSS.

If you put `float: left` style `<ul>`, and make your `<li>`s `display: block`, they should all be the same width.

Answer (score 1):

```
var max = 0;
$("ul.dropdown li").each(function(){
  if($(this).width() >= max ){
     max  = $(this).width();
  }
});

$("ul.dropdown li").width(max);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem myself, simply use this CSS:

```
ul{
  float: left;
}

ul li {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

I know it's a bit late but this answer drives me nuts, i searched forever for this easy snippet. Hopfully someone will help this.